# Clang thread safety with std::condition variable

Tags: c++, thread-safety, clang++

I have the following mutex classes (hopefully) implemented after the clang thread safety model. (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html)

```
class CAPABILITY( "mutex" ) Mutex : public std::mutex
{
  public:
    void lock() ACQUIRE()
    {
        std::mutex::lock();
    }

    void unlock() RELEASE()
    {
        std::mutex::unlock();
    }
};

class SCOPED_CAPABILITY LockGuard : public std::unique_lock< std::mutex >
{
  public:
        LockGuard( Mutex& mu ) ACQUIRE( mu ) : std::unique_lock< std::mutex >( mu )
        {
        }

        ~LockGuard() RELEASE()
        {
        }
};
```

The usage is as follows:

```
class Barrier
{
    ...

    Mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cv_ GUARDED_BY( mutex_ );
    std::size_t min_count_ GUARDED_BY( mutex_ );
    std::size_t count_ GUARDED_BY( mutex_ );

    bool Barrier::waitFor( const std::chrono::microseconds& duration )
    {
        LockGuard lock( mutex_ );
        if ( count_ >= min_count_ )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // WARNING IS IN THE LINE BELOW
            return cv_.wait_for( lock, duration, [this]() { return count_ >= min_count_; } );  
        }
    }
};
```

I get the clang warning:
`warning: reading variable 'count_' requires holding mutex 'mutex_' [-Wthread-safety-analysis]`.

Is the warning of the compiler (clang 3.8 with -Wthread-safety) correct? If yes, how exactly does the violation happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is not clear to the compiler, where the lambda expression is evaluated, it is necessary to annotate the lambda as well.

The correct line, which doesn't yield any error is

```
return cv_.wait_for( lock, duration, [this]() REQUIRES( mutex_ ) { return count_ >= min_count_; } );
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is very problematic. You are inheriting from `unique_lock`, but you are not constructing it properly! You have your own mutex, which you lock/unlock, but the one owned by `unique_lock` will remain uninitialized. Condition variable `wait_for` will call `release` on the parent lock, and will release unlocked mutex, leaving your mutex locked.

I do not see any reason to engage in this exercise of reimplementing locking in your custom classes. Remember, standard library classes are almost **never** meant to be inherited from.

Comment: We need to compile with several compilers and different stdlibs. However only clang offers this functionality inside its own lib. Therefore we need to reimplement it in our own code.

Comment: Than you'd have to reimplement pretty much everything. You can't just inherit it the way you did.

Comment: I've changed the code accordingly, the warning remains the same. Please be more detailed why inheritance should not be suitable.